# Update dictionary with occurence compared to another dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

I have 2 lists of dictionaries:

```
 list1= [{"id": "1e","name": "cup"},{"id": "4d","name": "cup"},{"id": "4c","name": "table"}]

 list2= [{"name": "cup"},{"name": "furniture"}]
```

I am trying the following:

1. To check if the 'name' key of each dict from list2 matches the 'name' key of each dict in list1,
2. If yes, update the dict in list2 with the corresponding ID's as a new list from list1

My program has a small error and I am not able to debug:

```
for i in range(len(list2)):
  for j in range(len(list1)):
    list3 = []
    if list2[i]['name'] == list1[j]['name']:
      list3.append(list1[j]['id'])
      list2[i].update(id= list3)
print(list2)


Output : [{'name': 'cup', 'id': ['4d']}, {'name': 'furniture'}]
expected Output : [{'name': 'cup', 'id': ['4d','1e']}, {'name': 'furniture', 'id': []}]
```

The id '1e' is not added to the list and I am not sure where do I check this. Has anyone an idea where is the mistake.

Thank you

Comment: List3 should be initialized outside the inner loop, but inside
 the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

just initialize list3 before loop. like this:

```
list1= [
    {"id": "1e","name": "cup"},
    {"id": "4d","name": "cup"},
    {"id": "4c","name": "table"}
]
list2= [
    {"name": "cup"},
    {"name": "furniture"}
]  
list3 = []
for i in range(len(list2)):
  for j in range(len(list1)):
    if list2[i]['name'] == list1[j]['name']:
      list3.append(list1[j]['id'])
      list2[i].update(id= list3)
print(list2)
```

in your code list3 will be empty each time and just save last round of loop values.